# After I install GnuRadio successfully, I can't find several hundred example files in /usr/local/share/gnuradio/examples

Tags: ubuntu, gnuradio

Everybody, I hava a difficulty.

When I install GunRadio successfully, , **I can't find several hundred example files** in `/usr/local/share/gnuradio/examples`, Which describe in [office wiki](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/HowToUse#Using-the-included-tools-and-utility-programs).

I use command line to install this software in`Ubuntu 14.04LTS`

```
sudo apt-get install gnuradio
```

and I can open this software successfully, but I can't find any example.

In my `/usr/local/share/gnuradio/examples` file folder which just include a empty file folder called fec.

**I hope to get help! Thanks!**

Comment: Hi Andrew, any news? Got it to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distributions differ on where they install stuff: The Ubuntu package repository definitely lists these examples as [contents of the gnuradio package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/gnuradio/filelist):

```
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/analog/fmtest.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/atsc/README
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/atsc/atsc_rx.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/audio/audio_copy.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/audio/audio_fft.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/audio/audio_play.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/audio/audio_to_file.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/audio/cvsd_sweep.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/audio/dial_tone.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/audio/dial_tone.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/audio/dial_tone_daemon.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/audio/dial_tone_wav.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/audio/mono_tone.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/audio/multi_tone.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/audio/noise.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/audio/spectrum_inversion.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/audio/test_resampler.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/channels/channel_tone_response.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/channels/demo_gmsk.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/channels/demo_ofdm.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/channels/demo_qam.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/channels/demo_quantization.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/channels/demo_spec_an.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/channels/demo_two_tone.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/demod/ber_simulation.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/demod/digital_freq_lock.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/demod/dpsk_loopback.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/demod/gfsk_loopback.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/demod/mpsk_demod.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/demod/pam_sync.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/demod/pam_timing.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/demod/test_corr_and_sync.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/demod/uhd_corr_and_sync_rx.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/demod/uhd_corr_and_sync_tx.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/example_costas.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/example_fll.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/example_timing.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/gen_whitener.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/narrowband/benchmark_rx.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/narrowband/benchmark_tx.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/narrowband/digital_bert_rx.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/narrowband/digital_bert_tx.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/narrowband/receive_path.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/narrowband/rx_voice.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/narrowband/transmit_path.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/narrowband/tunnel.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/narrowband/tx_voice.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/narrowband/uhd_interface.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/ofdm/benchmark_add_channel.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/ofdm/benchmark_rx.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/ofdm/benchmark_tx.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/ofdm/gr_plot_ofdm.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/ofdm/ofdm_loopback.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/ofdm/receive_path.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/ofdm/rx_ofdm.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/ofdm/transmit_path.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/ofdm/tunnel.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/ofdm/tx_ofdm.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/ofdm/uhd_interface.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/run_length.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/digital/snr_estimators.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/fcd/fcd_apt_rx.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/fcd/fcd_fft_wx.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/fcd/fcd_nfm_rx.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/filter/channelize.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/filter/chirp_channelize.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/filter/decimate.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/filter/fft_filter_ccc.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/filter/fir_filter_ccc.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/filter/fir_filter_fff.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/filter/gr_filtdes_api.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/filter/gr_filtdes_callback.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/filter/gr_filtdes_live_upd.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/filter/gr_filtdes_restrict.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/filter/interpolate.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/filter/reconstruction.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/filter/resampler.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/filter/resampler_demo.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/filter/synth_filter.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/filter/synth_to_chan.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/grc/simple/variable_config.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/grc/xmlrpc/readme.txt
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/grc/xmlrpc/xmlrpc_client.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/grc/xmlrpc/xmlrpc_client_script.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/grc/xmlrpc/xmlrpc_server.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/hf_explorer/README
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/hf_explorer/hfx.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/hf_explorer/hfx_help
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/hf_radio/README.TXT
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/hf_radio/hfir.sci
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/hf_radio/input.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/hf_radio/output.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/hf_radio/radio.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/hf_radio/radio.xml
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/hf_radio/ssb_taps
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/hf_radio/ssbagc.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/hf_radio/ssbdemod.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/hf_radio/startup.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/hf_radio/ui.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/metadata/file_metadata_sink.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/metadata/file_metadata_source.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/metadata/file_metadata_vector_sink.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/metadata/file_metadata_vector_source.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/mp-sched/README
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/mp-sched/affinity_set.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/mp-sched/plot_flops.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/mp-sched/run_synthetic.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/mp-sched/synthetic.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/mp-sched/wfm_rcv_pll_to_wav.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/network/audio_sink.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/network/audio_source.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/network/dial_tone_sink.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/network/dial_tone_source.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/network/vector_sink.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/network/vector_source.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/noaa/file_rx_hrpt.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/noaa/hrpt_decode.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/noaa/hrpt_demod.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/noaa/usrp_rx_hrpt.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/noaa/usrp_rx_hrpt_nogui.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/qt-gui/dark.qss
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/qt-gui/pyqt_const_c.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/qt-gui/pyqt_example_c.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/qt-gui/pyqt_example_f.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/qt-gui/pyqt_freq_c.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/qt-gui/pyqt_freq_f.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/qt-gui/pyqt_histogram_f.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/qt-gui/pyqt_time_c.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/qt-gui/pyqt_time_f.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/qt-gui/pyqt_time_raster_b.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/qt-gui/pyqt_time_raster_f.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/qt-gui/pyqt_waterfall_c.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/qt-gui/pyqt_waterfall_f.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/qt-gui/qtgui_tags_viewing.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/tags/test_file_tags.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/tags/uhd_burst_detector.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/README
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/fsm_files/awgn1o2_128.fsm
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/fsm_files/awgn1o2_16.fsm
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/fsm_files/awgn1o2_4.fsm
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/fsm_files/awgn1o2_8.fsm
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/fsm_files/awgn2o3_16.fsm
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/fsm_files/awgn2o3_4.fsm
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/fsm_files/awgn2o3_4_msb.fsm
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/fsm_files/awgn2o3_4_msbG.fsm
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/fsm_files/awgn2o3_8.fsm
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/fsm_files/awgn2o4_4.fsm
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/fsm_files/disconnected.fsm
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/fsm_files/rep3.fsm
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/fsm_files/rep5.fsm
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/fsm_files/simple.fsm
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/fsm_utils.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/interference_cancellation.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/pccc.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/pccc1.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/readme.txt
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/sccc.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/sccc1.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/test_sccc_hard.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/test_sccc_soft.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/test_sccc_turbo.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/test_tcm.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/test_tcm_combined.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/test_tcm_parallel.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/test_turbo_equalization.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/test_turbo_equalization1.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/test_turbo_equalization2.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/test_viterbi_equalization.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/trellis/test_viterbi_equalization1.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/uhd/fm_tx4.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/uhd/fm_tx_2_daughterboards.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/uhd/max_power.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/uhd/uhd_const_wave.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/uhd/uhd_dpsk_mod.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/uhd/uhd_fft.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/uhd/uhd_rx_dpsk.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/uhd/uhd_two_tone_loopback.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/uhd/uhd_tx_dpsk.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/uhd/uhd_wbfm_receive.grc
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/uhd/usrp_am_mw_rcv.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/uhd/usrp_nbfm_ptt.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/uhd/usrp_nbfm_rcv.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/uhd/usrp_spectrum_sense.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/uhd/usrp_tv_rcv.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/uhd/usrp_tv_rcv_nogui.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/uhd/usrp_wfm_rcv.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/uhd/usrp_wfm_rcv2_nogui.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/uhd/usrp_wfm_rcv_fmdet.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/uhd/usrp_wfm_rcv_nogui.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/uhd/usrp_wfm_rcv_pll.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/uhd/usrp_wfm_rcv_sca.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/uhd/usrp_wxapt_rcv.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/vocoder/alaw_audio_loopback.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/vocoder/codec2_audio_loopback.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/vocoder/cvsd_audio_loopback.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/vocoder/g721_audio_loopback.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/vocoder/g723_24_audio_loopback.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/vocoder/g723_40_audio_loopback.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/vocoder/gsm_audio_loopback.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/vocoder/ulaw_audio_loopback.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/volk_benchmark/README
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/volk_benchmark/volk_math.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/volk_benchmark/volk_plot.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/volk_benchmark/volk_test_funcs.py
/usr/share/gnuradio/examples/volk_benchmark/volk_types.py
```

`/usr/local/` is the default destination in the case where you compile GNU Radio yourself, only.